# How do I pass variable when using Python subprocess module

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file, subprocess

I'm trying to use python Subprocess module to enable/disable Ethernet connection from python code. Below is my code in which the first step is looking for the available "Ethernet Connections" and the next step enables/disables the ethernet connection according to the parameter passed in "%interfaces%".

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=3*" %%A in ('netsh interface show interface') do set interface=%%B

netsh interface set interface %interface%  ENABLED
```

Now when using in python I couldn't pass the variable, not sure if it's even possible though. Passing only command as below works as expected:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('netsh interface set interface Ethernet10 ENABLED')
```

I want to do something like:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call (set x = 'Ethernet0')
subprocess.call('netsh interface set interface x  ENABLED')
```

Answer (score 2):

[subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) takes a list as an argument:

```
subprocess.call(['netsh', 'interface', 'set', 'interface', x, 'ENABLED'])
```

You could instead pass `shell=True` and your string would work, but it is a security risk, since an user could for example call another command by using `$(command_here)`

If you still want to use a string, you could use `shlex.split`.

Comment: thanks idjaw, it worked as expected. One more question now when trying to use subprocess for below code doesn't work. I tried to separate it out in individual strings and in a single string as well using shell=True but didn't helped.

for /f "skip=2 tokens=3*" %%A in ('netsh interface show interface') do set interface=%%B

Comment: this is how I seperated.
import subprocess

y = subprocess.call(['for /f', 'skip=2 tokens=3*', '%%A in', 'netsh', 'interface', 'show', 'interface', 'do', 'set', 'interface=%%B'])
print y

Answer (score 0):

Use string formatting, interpolation, or concatenation:

```
x = 'Ethernet10'
subprocess.call('netsh interface set interface ' + x + ' ENABLED')
```

Comment: Not quite. The way you are trying to structure that as a single string, you will have to pass `shell=True`. However, the preferred/safer way to do this is to leave `shell=False` and structure the call as a list. Pretty much like the other answer that was just posted.